# Django Populate Hidden Input with request.user.get_username()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a model:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='entity')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    #...More Fields
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.entity
```

I have a corresponding model form and model formset rendered by crispy-forms:

```
class AlertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'user': HiddenInput(),
            'entity': ModelSelect2(url='eda', attrs={'data-minimum-input-length': 2}),

AlertFormSet = modelformset_factory(Alert, extra=1, exclude=(), form=AlertForm)
```

I have a view built on top of the formset:

```
def alerts(request):
    helper = AlertFormsetHelper()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST)
        for form in formset:
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.has_changed():
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        entity = form.cleaned_data['entity']
                        messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS: Alert for %s was dispositioned' % entity)
        return redirect('alerts')
    else:
        query = Alert.objects.filter(disposition='')
        paginator = Paginator(query, 12)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            objects = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            objects = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            objects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        page_query = query.filter(id__in=[object.id for object in objects])
        formset = AlertFormSet(queryset=page_query.order_by('entity'))
        context = {'objects':objects, 'formset':formset, 'helper':helper}
    return render(request, 'alerts/alerts.html', context)
```

I would like `user` to be populated by the current `REMOTE_USER` username that can be accessed with `request.user.get_username()`. `user.get_username` is performing correctly in my template and showing the current user. However, when I attempt to automatically populate the field and POST the data to the DB, the record is not posted. I tried changing the view to this:

```
def alerts(request):
        helper = AlertFormsetHelper()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST)
            for form in formset:
                if form.is_valid():
                    if form.has_changed():
                        if form.is_valid():
                            form.save()
                            entity = form.cleaned_data['entity']
                            user = request.user.get_username()
                            messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS: Alert for %s was dispositioned' % entity)
            return redirect('alerts')
```

I tried creating a new instance of the form being saved, applying the user operation, then saving the instance. This also resulted in nothing.

How should I access the current user and automatically populate a blank, hidden field prior to saving the form in a formset to the DB?

**Formset Save Update:**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.instance.user = request.user.get_username()
            formset.save()
            entity = formset.cleaned_data['entity']
            messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS: Alert for %s was dispositioned' % entity)
```

**Second Formset Save Update:**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.user = request.user.get_username()
                instance.entity = instance.cleaned_data['entity']
                instance.save()
                messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS: Alert for %s was dispositioned' % entity)
```

Comment: You may be able to simplify your view slightly by using [`formset.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) (perhaps with `commit=False`). You get access to `formset.changed_objects`, so you wouldn't have to check `form.has_changed()` for each form.

Comment: i have tried and failed to accomplish this tweak a few times recently...if you have any thoughts on my attempt in the update to my question, please let me know. otherwise i can post a new question.

Comment: Setting `formset.instance` won't work, you need to alter the individual form or instance. Your second attempt looks along the right lines. You shouldn't need to do `instance.entity = instance.cleaned_data['entity']` - `instance.entity` should already be set.

Comment: still results in a redirect without comitting anything to the DB. i will keep digging - thank you very much for your help

Comment: You might be getting odd results because you are specifying a form for GET requests but not for POST requests. This means that for post requests, the queryset defaults to `Alert.objects.all()`, and the formset is invalid because there are lots of forms 'missing'. Note that the usual approach is to display the formset with errors when it's invalid (which makes it easier to debug), and only redirect when a valid formset has been submitted.

Comment: good point. i'm tried adding a queryset to the formset under `if request.method == 'post':`, but it still resulted in nothing. maybe the pagination is causing some issues since the query set is not actually all on the page? i will work on better error checking as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need a hidden input here. I would use a form that doesn't include the user field.

```
class AlertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields = ['entity', ...] . # don't include user
        ...
```

Then in your view, you can set `form.instance.user` before saving the form.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.user = request.user.get_username()
    form.save()
```

Comment: how would you do that in a class-based view with a form?

Comment: @NFSpeedy you probably want to override the `form_valid` method. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092544/django-and-the-form-valid-method) might help. If you’re still stuck, please ask a new question.